# The hardest [button] to button

Tags: discussion

Why is the [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button) tag a thing?

Most of its [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/button/topusers) only answered one or two questions with this tag (and they are specialists in something else, not buttons). If you check the [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button?sort=newest) tab for this tag you'll see it's heavily misused by new users and doesn't add any value to the questions.

It may be a valueable tag in ux.stackexchange, but is it necessary here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I don't think it should be burminated as buttons are GUI components. There is also a class named `Button` in the awt library.

Comment: So it then means the tag is ambiguous and should be split, right? I'm not asking for burnination, I just wanna understand why this tag exists if it has no value

Comment: @CoolGuy: I wouldn't call that two different uses, but a single one. Though I'm not sure that really makes the tag all that useful. (I think the tag is borderline-useless.)

Comment: As there is a UIButton and jButton tag, shouldn't there be a awtButton tag. There is really no use of the general Button tag.